# keep first log_ID same as a parent_ID for every multiple insert query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP program which insert 4 row once when run. I want to keep first `log_ID(auto incremental)` same `parent_ID` for every 4 row.

like Below:

on 1st run program:

```
log_ID    name  parent_ID
======   =====  ==========
1         abc    1
2         def    1
3         ghi    1
4         jkl    1
```

on 2nd run program:

```
log_ID  name    parent_ID
======  =====   ==========
1        abc     1
2        def     1
3        ghi     1
4        jkl     1
5        xyz     5
6        abc     5
7        stu     5
8        jkl     5
```

Comment: parent_id != parent_ID != parant_key, im confused

Comment: where is your code for inserting data...

Comment: @SherinJose i have insert code in php..

Comment: How can I assume your code...post it..

Comment: @SherinJose  check insert query. i didn't put all code.

Comment: @SherinJose.. i hope u understand my question

Comment: Okay ...but actually which is your code for inserting the 4 rows...is it in the function `donwload()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47381/discussion-between-codemania-and-sherin-jose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brief idea about how you can handle the problem..

```
<?php
$query1 =   "YOUR FIRST INSERT QUERY";
mysql_query($query1);
$last_log_id    =   mysql_insert_id();  //here you will get the log_id generated for the previous query (auto incremental)

//set the above last_log_id as parent_id of the previous row. ie., update query for row with `log_id` $last_log_id

$update_query   =   "YOUR UPDATE QUERY FOR FIRST ROW";

$query2 =   "YOUR SECOND INSERT QUERY WITH PARENT_ID AS $last_log_id";
mysql_query($query2);
$query3 =   "YOUR THIRD INSERT QUERY WITH PARENT_ID AS $last_log_id";
mysql_query($query3);
$query4 =   "YOUR FOURTH INSERT QUERY WITH PARENT_ID AS $last_log_id";
mysql_query($query4);
?>
```